# What is the Battle of Chyron Belt?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

After Leia is recovered from space and left to recover in what looks to be a glass MRI machine, command of the fleet is given to Vice Admiral Holdo. Poe asks Ello Asty if this is the "Battle of Chyron Belt Holdo?".

What was the Battle of Chyron Belt? Do we learn anymore about it in additional materials?

Comment: It happened shortly after the Battle of Tanaab, where Lando pulled that maneuver.

Comment: @CBredlow Oh... That one! Nope, still not getting it...

Comment: Shouldn't we close this as future works policy?

Comment: @C.Koca - No, because there's no obvious expectation that this will be answered in a future work

Comment: nothing in the Visual Dictionary or the Incredible Cross-Sections for The Last Jedi... sorry

Comment: I assumed the battle was just a usage of the common movie shorthand method to introduce Holdo as a [More than meets the eye](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MoreThanMeetsTheEye)/[Hidden badass](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HiddenBadass) (TV Tropes warning!) type character, so that her perceived heel turn in ignoring Poe and seemingly doing nothing, only to later do a second _volte face_ would be more impactful from an as before unseen character. However, I wouldn't be surprised if they retconned the battle into a later prequel work!

Comment: That reference is all we know about it

Answer (score 1):

We just don't know.

In all media that the [Battle of Chyron Belt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Chyron_Belt) or [the Chyron Belt](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Chyron_Belt) has been brought up, it only gets mentioned with no other context. Neither have a page in the official [Star Wars Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank), nor any of the reference books.

[image]

It appears to have been an intentional use of the "[Cryptic Background Reference](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrypticBackgroundReference)" trope.